# Help with Android UI ListView problems

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-listview, highlighting

To understand this question, [first read how this method works.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#onInterceptTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29)

I am trying to implements a drag and drop [ListView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html), it's going alright but have run into
a road block. So I don't have to handled everything, I am intercepting(but returning false) [MotionEvents](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) sent to the ListView, letting it handle scrolling and stuff. When I want to start dragging a item, I then return true and handled all the dragging stuff. Everything is working fine except for one thing. The drag(drag and drop) is started when it is determined that a long press as a occurred(in onInterceptTouchEvent). I get the [Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) for the image that I drag around like so. itemPositition being the index of the item that was selected.

(omitting irrelevant parts)

```
...
View dragItem = mListView.getChildAt(itemPosition);
dragItem.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(dragItem.getDrawingCache());
mDragImage = new ImageView(mContext);
mDragImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
...
```

The problem is, mDragImage is a solid black like this.
[image: A solid back bitmap]

But, if I don't let ListView handle anything. As in, I start the drag on [ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) and stop on [ACTION_UP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP), mDragImage looks has expected(but I obviously lose scrolling abilities).

[image: A good bitmap]

Since the drag is started with a long press, the ListView is given the opportunity to do things before the long press occurs. This is my guess as to why this is happening. When a item is pressed, it is highlighted by the ListView. Somewhere in doing so, it is messing with the bitmap. So when I go to get it, it's in a weird state(all black).

I see two options for fixing this, neither of which I know how to do.

1. Create a image from scratch.
2. Handle the highlighting myself(if that is the problem).

Option two seems a better one to me, except that I looked at the documentation and the source code and could not find out how to do so. Here are some things I have done/tried.

- I set [setOnItemClickListener(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemClickListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener%29) and
  [setOnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnItemSelectedListener%28android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener%29)(...) with a empty method(highlighting
  still happens). (Before anyone suggests it, calling
  [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29) results in a runtime error.)
- I also looked into trying to get the ListView to make a new item
  (for option 2), but could not find a way.
- Spent 45ish minutes looking through the source code and
  documentation trying to pinpoint where the highlighting was
  happening(I never found it).

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

(EDIT1 START)

So I don't actually know if onLongClickListener is working, I made an error before thinking it was. I am trying to set it up right now, will update when I find out if it does.

(EDIT1 END)

Last minute edit before post. I tried using [onLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) just now, and the image is good. I would still like to know if there is another way. How I have to use onLongClickListener to get things working is ugly, but it works. I also spent so much time trying to figure this out, it would be nice to find out the answer. I still want to be able to change/handle the highlight color, the default orangeish color is not pretty. Oh and sorry about the length of the post. I could not think of way of making it shorter, while supplying all the information I thought was needed.

Answer (score 0):

use this code, it's allows operation drug and drop in ListView:

```
public class DraggableListView extends ListView {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "tasks365";

    private static final int END_OF_LIST_POSITION = -2;

    private DropListener mDropListener;
    private int draggingItemHoverPosition;
    private int dragStartPosition; // where was the dragged item originally
    private int mUpperBound; // scroll the view when dragging point is moving out of this bound
    private int mLowerBound; // scroll the view when dragging point is moving out of this bound
    private int touchSlop;
    private Dragging dragging;
    private GestureDetector longPressDetector;

    public DraggableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.listViewStyle);
    }

    public DraggableListView(final Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        touchSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).getScaledTouchSlop();

        longPressDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(), new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(final MotionEvent e) {
                int x = (int) e.getX();
                final int y = (int) e.getY();

                int itemnum = pointToPosition(x, y);
                if (itemnum == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                    return;
                }

                if (dragging != null) {
                    dragging.stop();
                    dragging = null;
                }

                final View item = getChildAt(itemnum - getFirstVisiblePosition());
                item.setPressed(false);
                dragging = new Dragging(getContext());
                dragging.start(y, ((int) e.getRawY()) - y, item);
                draggingItemHoverPosition = itemnum;
                dragStartPosition = draggingItemHoverPosition;

                int height = getHeight();
                mUpperBound = Math.min(y - touchSlop, height / 3);
                mLowerBound = Math.max(y + touchSlop, height * 2 / 3);
            }
        });

        setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")

            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> paramAdapterView, View paramView, int paramInt, long paramLong) {
                // Return true to let AbsListView reset touch mode
                // Without this handler, the pressed item will keep highlight.
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    /* pointToPosition() doesn't consider invisible views, but we need to, so implement a slightly different version. */
    private int myPointToPosition(int x, int y) {
        if (y < 0) {
            return getFirstVisiblePosition();
        }
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            final View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.getHitRect(frame);
            if (frame.contains(x, y)) {
                return getFirstVisiblePosition() + i;
            }
        }
        if ((x >= frame.left) && (x < frame.right) && (y >= frame.bottom)) {
            return END_OF_LIST_POSITION;
        }
        return INVALID_POSITION;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        if (longPressDetector.onTouchEvent(ev)) {
            return true;
        }

        if ((dragging == null) || (mDropListener == null)) {
            // it is not dragging, or there is no drop listener
            return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        }

        int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (ev.getAction()) {

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            dragging.stop();
            dragging = null;

            if (mDropListener != null) {
                if (draggingItemHoverPosition == END_OF_LIST_POSITION) {
                    mDropListener.drop(dragStartPosition, getCount() - 1);
                } else if (draggingItemHoverPosition != INVALID_POSITION) {
                    mDropListener.drop(dragStartPosition, draggingItemHoverPosition);
                }
            }
            resetViews();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            int x = (int) ev.getX();
            int y = (int) ev.getY();
            dragging.drag(x, y);
            int position = dragging.calculateHoverPosition();
            if (position != INVALID_POSITION) {
                if ((action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || (position != draggingItemHoverPosition)) {
                    draggingItemHoverPosition = position;
                    doExpansion();
                }
                scrollList(y);
            }
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void doExpansion() {
        int expanItemViewIndex = draggingItemHoverPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition();
        if (draggingItemHoverPosition >= dragStartPosition) {
            expanItemViewIndex++;
        }

       // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Dragging item hovers over position " + draggingItemHoverPosition + ", expand item at index "
         //       + expanItemViewIndex);

        View draggingItemOriginalView = getChildAt(dragStartPosition - getFirstVisiblePosition());
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            View itemView = getChildAt(i);
            if (itemView == null) {
                break;
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = itemView.getLayoutParams();
            int height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            if (itemView.equals(draggingItemOriginalView)) {
                height = 1;
            } else if (i == expanItemViewIndex) {
                height = itemView.getHeight() + dragging.getDraggingItemHeight();
            }
            params.height = height;
            itemView.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reset view to original height.
     */
    private void resetViews() {
        for (int i = 0;; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            if (v == null) {
                layoutChildren(); // force children to be recreated where needed
                v = getChildAt(i);
                if (v == null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = v.getLayoutParams();
            params.height = LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            v.setLayoutParams(params);
        }
    }

    private void resetScrollBounds(int y) {
        int height = getHeight();
        if (y >= height / 3) {
            mUpperBound = height / 3;
        }
        if (y <= height * 2 / 3) {
            mLowerBound = height * 2 / 3;
        }
    }

    private void scrollList(int y) {
        resetScrollBounds(y);

        int height = getHeight();
        int speed = 0;
        if (y > mLowerBound) {
            // scroll the list up a bit
            speed = y > (height + mLowerBound) / 2 ? 16 : 4;
        } else if (y < mUpperBound) {
            // scroll the list down a bit
            speed = y < mUpperBound / 2 ? -16 : -4;
        }
        if (speed != 0) {
            int ref = pointToPosition(0, height / 2);
            if (ref == AdapterView.INVALID_POSITION) {
                //we hit a divider or an invisible view, check somewhere else
                ref = pointToPosition(0, height / 2 + getDividerHeight() + 64);
            }
            View v = getChildAt(ref - getFirstVisiblePosition());
            if (v != null) {
                int pos = v.getTop();
                setSelectionFromTop(ref, pos - speed);
            }
        }
    }

    public void setDropListener(DropListener l) {
        mDropListener = l;
    }

    public interface DropListener {
        void drop(int from, int to);
    }

    class Dragging {

        private Context context;
        private WindowManager windowManager;
        private WindowManager.LayoutParams mWindowParams;
        private ImageView mDragView;
        private Bitmap mDragBitmap;
        private int coordOffset;
        private int mDragPoint; // at what offset inside the item did the user grab it
        private int draggingItemHeight;
        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int lastY;

        public Dragging(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
            windowManager = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService("window");
        }

        /**
         * @param y
         * @param offset - the difference in y axis between screen coordinates and coordinates in this view
         * @param view - which view is dragged
         */
        public void start(int y, int offset, View view) {
            this.y = y;
            lastY = y;
            this.coordOffset = offset;
            mDragPoint = y - view.getTop();

            draggingItemHeight = view.getHeight();

            mDragView = new ImageView(context);
            mDragView.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.alert_light_frame);

            // Create a copy of the drawing cache so that it does not get recycled
            // by the framework when the list tries to clean up memory
            view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            mDragBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getDrawingCache());
            mDragView.setImageBitmap(mDragBitmap);

            mWindowParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
            mWindowParams.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
            mWindowParams.x = 0;
            mWindowParams.y = y - mDragPoint + coordOffset;
            mWindowParams.height = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            mWindowParams.width = WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
            mWindowParams.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN;
            mWindowParams.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
            mWindowParams.windowAnimations = 0;

            windowManager.addView(mDragView, mWindowParams);
        }

        public void drag(int x, int y) {
            lastY = this.y;
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            mWindowParams.y = y - mDragPoint + coordOffset;
            windowManager.updateViewLayout(mDragView, mWindowParams);
        }

        public void stop() {
            if (mDragView != null) {
                windowManager.removeView(mDragView);
                mDragView.setImageDrawable(null);
                mDragView = null;
            }
            if (mDragBitmap != null) {
                mDragBitmap.recycle();
                mDragBitmap = null;
            }
        }

        public int getDraggingItemHeight() {
            return draggingItemHeight;
        }

        public int calculateHoverPosition() {
            int adjustedY = (int) (y - mDragPoint + (Math.signum(y - lastY) + 2) * draggingItemHeight / 2);
            // Log.v(LOG_TAG, "calculateHoverPosition(): lastY=" + lastY + ", y=" + y + ", adjustedY=" + adjustedY);
            int pos = myPointToPosition(0, adjustedY);
            if (pos >= 0) {
                if (pos >= dragStartPosition) {
                    pos -= 1;
                }
            }
            return pos;
        }

    }
}
```